# Which npm web server can I use with url rewriting

Tags: angularjs, webserver, npm, single-page-application

I making SPA with AngularJS and need a local web server that supports rewrite url functionality. All of the requests like `/home`, `/profile/1`, `/products?id=12` should return index.html in the root folder.
I tried [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server), [local-web-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/local-web-server) but non of these include redirect functionality. I guess [superstatic](https://www.npmjs.com/package/superstatic) should work, but it returns 404 error all the time for some reason

Answer (score 1):

Try [expressjs](http://expressjs.com/)

You can use something like

```
 app.route('/*')
    .get(function(req, res) {
      res.sendFile(path.resolve(app.get('appPath') + '/index.html'));
    });
```

You can checkout [this](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack) generator

Comment: It is not exact way that I search, but it can work. One problem, in this case all static files js/css/img use this route and return index.html, how can I avoid it?

Comment: express-static is for that, anything under public folder, for example - `app.use(express.static(path.join(config.root, 'public')));` - for more info - check at https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack/blob/master/app/templates/server/config/express.js

Comment: I found the cause, the js and css files should not contain `public/` in path. Thanks for the help, I just voted your answer in case someone has a variant just with config in a server.

Answer (score 0):

Express does allow a '*' and it will also allow regular expressions.

In most cases in production you should probably serve your webapp from nginx or something and reverse proxy the express api through nginx and link them together.  nginx will cache much better and the like. (and probably be much more secure)

However... Use gulpjs (I think you can with grunt as well), and then use http://www.browsersync.io/ and https://github.com/shakyShane/browser-sync-spa to reload your frontend and that will get you by for developing if you're just frustrated with routing

Answer (score -1):

I had similar problem with Angular2 application where I were about to demonstrate its functionality in some demo. In my case npm http-server was working by using trick with its proxy.

I just run my website with `--proxy http://localhost:4200?` parameter (don't forget the `?` at the end) like this

```
http-server --port 4200 --proxy http://localhost:4200? ./
```

Or in default http-server way (if you are happy with default 8080 port, and serving from current directory):

```
http-server --proxy http://localhost:8080?
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed, it seems like OP's problem would be fixed with this as well. If not, he is doing something else wrong. Not sure why you received a -2.